# if-else vs if-else-if-else

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Is there any difference between using if else if and else or if else and other conditions in else. For example,

```
if (i == 5)
  printf("i is 5");
else if (i > 5)
  printf("i is greater than 5");
else
  printf("i is less than 5");
```

OR

```
if (i == 5)
  printf("i is 5");
else {
  if (i > 5)
    printf("i is greater than 5");
  else
    printf("i is less than 5");
}
```

There is no difference in execution. Both the snippets will give same result but is it like we should use the later one or the first one just because one is a better programming practice and other is not.

Comment: Pick the one that is easier to read. The second one looks strange/wrong. Just because it works, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I would say generally since you are testing the same data throughout, keep in in the same loop of statements. Only break into another level if you are testing other things.

Comment: The first one is clearer/easier to read. In general, avoid excessive nesting when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no functional difference between using `else if` vs `else { if`.  It is purely a style decision.

I venture to say the majority of developers though prefer `else if`.  Using `else { if` causes needless indentation for logic based on the same data.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to prefer the first for cases where the different "legs" are "on par" with each other.  For cases where the second if condition is conceptually a subcase of the else then the second form is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever most clearly conveys the situation:

```
if (file_opened_successfully)
...
else
{
   if (file_does_not_exist)
   ...
   else if (file_permissions_not_set)
   ...
   else if (file_wrong_type)
   ...
   else
   ...
}
```

The outer decision is strictly binary; either we could open the file or we couldn't.  If we could open the file, we process it normally, otherwise we need to process the error.

However, there are multiple possible reasons why we couldn't open the file, and our error processing depends on which of the reasons turns out to be the case.  So that's a multi-way branch, instead of a strictly binary branch.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the first approach if the condition is related to the first If, otherwise i would use number 2, but its just how you feel comfortable.